# Flling a two-dimensional array with buttons

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, button

I have a litte problem here. I have a two-dimensional array which is [5,5] big.
I have a windows form with 25 buttons. Now I want to store the buttons in the object array, but my problem is, how do I tell the program to know which button to put in the array? Is it possible in some kind of this way:

```
//_array[i] = button(i);
```

This is my first time storing objects in an array and I dont know how to do that.

EDIT: The buttons have all the standard names (button1,button,button3...)

EDIT2: I know how to it by hand `(_array[x,y] = button1)` but I want to know how to it ith a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the controls by using [`IEnumerable.OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
//get all buttons and order them by name
var buttons = Controls.OfType<Button>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        _array[i, j] = buttons[i*5+j];
```

Comment: "= buttons[i*5+j];" gives me this error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Button>'

Answer (score 1):

You can access the buttons using their name as index of the `Controls` collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        _array[i, k] = Controls["Button" + (5 * i + k + 1).ToString()];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
  _array[i,j] = Controls.Item["Button" + (i*5 +j).ToString()];
```

Comment: for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
      _array[i,j] = Controls.Item["Button" + (i*5 +j).ToString()];

Comment: I see, I asked my question wrong. I know how to fill by hand, but I would like to let the program do it by itself.

Comment: do I need a specific namespace for "Controls.Item" ?

Comment: No there is no "Controls.Items"